# После клика по ссылке вокруг нее появляется голубоватая рамка, как исправить?

Tags: html, css3

пробовал ставить:

`border: 0;`

и

```
:focus{
border: 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: свойству outline поставьте 0

Comment: Спасибо огромное, специально искал, мне помогло 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в css к селектору добавьте

```
outline: none
```

или

```
outline: 0
```